# ggplot2: plotting non-contiguous time durations as a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot various events as a function of the date (x-axis) and start time (y-axis) on which they began. The data/code are as follows:

```
date<-c("2013-06-05","2013-06-05","2013-06-04","2013-06-04","2013-06-04","2013-06-04","2013-06-04",
    "2013-06-04","2013-06-04","2013-06-03","2013-06-03","2013-06-03","2013-06-03","2013-06-03",
    "2013-06-02","2013-06-02","2013-06-02","2013-06-02","2013-06-02","2013-06-02","2013-06-02")
start <-c("07:36:00","01:30:00","22:19:00","22:12:00","20:16:00","19:19:00","09:00:00",
     "06:45:00","01:03:00","22:15:00","19:05:00","08:59:00","08:01:00","07:08:00",
     "23:24:00","20:39:00","18:53:00","16:57:00","15:07:00","14:33:00","13:24:00")
duration <-c(0.5,6.1,2.18,0.12,1.93,0.95,10.32,
         2.25,5.7,2.78,3.17,9.03,0.95,0.88,
         7.73,2.75,1.77,1.92,1.83,0.57,1.13)
event <-c("AF201","SS431","BE201","CD331","HG511","CD331","WQ115",
      "CD331","SS431","WQ115","HG511","WQ115","CD331","AF201",
      "SS431","WQ115","HG511","WQ115","CD331","AS335","CD331")

df<-data.frame(date,start,duration,event)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date),as.POSIXct(start,format='%H:%M:%S'),color=event))
p <- p+geom_point(alpha = I(6/10),size=5) 
p + ylab("time (hr)") + xlab("date") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d")) +
scale_y_datetime(labels = date_format("%H"))+
scale_colour_hue(h=c(360, 90))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=0))
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

**Question:** Instead of simply indicating the start time of the event with a single point (shown above), how can I plot a bar that spans the time duration of the event? As shown in the data frame above I have this duration data (in hours). Alternatively, I could supply a 'stop time' (not shown).

I'm imagining the solution would look something like a stacked bar chart. However, a bar chart isn't quite right as it assumes the bar starts at the bottom of the plot and that the vertically stacked events have no gaps between them. My events may be non-contiguous -- 'starting' and 'stopping' at various positions along the y-axis. The solution will also have to take into consideration that 1) some events may ultimately be concurrent (overlap in time) and 2) some events will span multiple days.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks (+1s) to @Michele and @alexwhan for your input. Using geom_rect I was able to get all of the events which occur on the same date on the same point on the x axis. (I'm anticipating that this data set may ultimately include many months of events.)

```
df<-data.frame(date,start,duration,event)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(xmin=as.Date(date),xmax=as.Date(date)+1,
                    ymin=as.POSIXct(start,format='%H:%M:%S'),
                    ymax=as.POSIXct(start,format='%H:%M:%S')+duration*3600,
                    fill=event))
p <- p+geom_rect(alpha = I(8/10)) 
p + ylab("time") + xlab("date") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d")) +
scale_y_datetime(labels = date_format("%H"))+
scale_colour_hue(h=c(360, 90))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=0))
```

... resulting in this:
[image]

This is pretty close to what I was aiming for.
I think I can deal with the potential overplotting issue by adjusting the alpha. 
Ideally I'd like the y axis to include just a single day (00 to 00). To do this I guess I'll probably need to reformat the data such that events with durations that extend beyond midnight are reallocated to the next day. (Not sure how to do this in R.)

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you want - @Michele's answer seemed good, I wasn't clear if you wanted to to use `geom_rect` because it would make for thicker lines (if so, just change the line width), or if there was another reason. I decided to give it a go using `geom_rect` to enable dodging. I've plotted it with the starting date on the x axis, and the start and end times on y. I've set up the data slightly differently to enable that. If you're after something different, try to make it explicit, but at least here's another option:

```
df<-data.frame(date,start,duration,event)

df <- transform(df,
                start = as.POSIXct(paste(date, start)),
                end   = as.POSIXct(paste(date, start)) + duration*3600)

df <- df[c("event", "start", "end")]

df$date <- strptime(df$start, "%Y-%m-%d")
df$start.new <- format(df$start, format = "%H:%M:%S")
df$end.new <- format(df$end, format = "%H:%M:%S")
df$day <- factor(as.POSIXct(df$date))
levels(df$day) <- 1:4
df$day <- as.numeric(as.character(df$day))
df$event.int <- df$event
levels(df$event.int) <- 1:7
df$event.int <- as.numeric(as.character(df$event.int))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(day, start)) + geom_rect(aes(ymin = start, ymax = end,
                                            xmin = (day - 0.45) + event.int/10,
                                            xmax = (day - 0.35) + event.int/10,
                                            fill = event)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = 1:4,breaks = 1:4, labels = sort(unique(date)),
                   name = "Start date") + ylab("Duration")
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice solution as well! however (to me) using `date` on x axis and `data-time` on y axis may make the chart more difficult to be understood especially for senior manager or people looking at the data for the 1st time. What about `Datetime` on x axis (you already use it but I mean show it) and the duration in hours or fraction of days on the y-axis? But anyway, this method looks nicer, you immediately see the colours! With my method you could benefit from the opportunity if using the y-axis or the legend for showing something else, since they are basically redundant!

Comment: @Michele I agree. As you pointed out, the real question here is what is the best way to visualise the data - which is a matter of the specific communication needs, and not really an SO issue. All good practice though!

Answer (score 3):

try this method. Probably it's different to what you planned but I think it's a quite clear way to show your data:

```
df<-data.frame(date,start,duration,event)

df <- transform(df,
                start = as.POSIXct(paste(date, start)),
                end   = as.POSIXct(paste(date, start)) + duration*3600)

df <- df[c("event", "start", "end")]

library(reshape2)

df <- melt(df, id.vars="event")
df$value <- as.POSIXct(df$value, origin=as.Date("1970-01-01"))

df <- df[order(df$event, df$value),]

df$eventID <- rep(seq(1, nrow(df)/2, 1), each=2)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(value, event, group=eventID, color=event))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this effort! It is indeed a clear representation of the data, but perhaps somewhat less concise than what I was looking for. I'm now thinking that using geom_rect() might be my best approach -- setting the event duration with ymin and ymax.

Comment: @Kappa visualisation technique choice is often just up to the analyst/consultant and as specified I knew you were after something a bit different. But I just want to say that you'll be likely to have overplotting with `geom_rect` so, in case you may need/want something without it you could consider my method (with maybe some change in line type, colour, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Combining the benefits of: (i) y-axis containing a single ~24 hour period; (ii) events not overlapping; (iii) events labelled within the graph in addition to the legend; and (iv) concise code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Re-create data frame
df <- data_frame(date, start, duration, event) %>%
    mutate(start_dt = as.POSIXct(paste(date, start), tz = 'UTC'),
           start_hr = hour(start_dt),
           end_dt = start_dt + duration * 3600,
           end_hr = hour(end_dt) + (as.Date(end_dt) - as.Date(start_dt)) * 24)

# Plot
df %>% ggplot() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = event, y = start_hr, xend = event, yend = end_hr,
                     color = event, size = 1)) +
    facet_wrap(~ date, nrow = 1) +
    guides(size = 'none')
```

Image of plot:

[image: Image of plot]