# ggplot: how to omit periods for a time duration bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've cleaned up a larger dataframe to a simple table that looks something like this (*note this is a small sample of a couple hundred rows*):

```
Name<-c("Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Anne","Anne","Anne","Anne","Anne","Anne","Joe","Joe")
start_event <-c(0,266,352,354,553,0,36,192,206,458,997,1102,1198)
end_event <-c(27.5,296,354,402,561,27.5,71,203,217,515,1033,1109,1215)
duration <-c(27.5,30,2,48,8,27.5,35,11,11,57,36,7,17)
run<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2)
df<-data.frame(Name,run,start_event,end_event,duration)
```

My goal is to create a graph that has the names on the **y-axis**, the total event duration on the **x-axis** (the min. would be the start_event and the max would be the final end_event).

For each person, a bar would represent the duration of their activity, from start to end. There would be gaps with no bars for the times they were not active.

I've tried mashing together some code from another example (link below) using either geom_rect, geom_bar, and attempts with geom_line, but am having issues with discrete/continuous values.

For reference to help visually frame this, this answer provided for this Q produces a similar result I would like to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130467

Dodging the bars/rectangles is not needed, stacked in a single horizontal line is preferred.

Thank you in advance for any guidance/help!

Comment: This sounds like a Gantt chart. I think you find some of [these Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[r]%20[ggplot]%20gantt) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `geom_segment`     :

```
ggplot(df,aes(y=Name,yend=Name,x=start_event,xend=end_event,color=Name)) + geom_segment(size=6)
```

[image]